# Can two different double integrals with same size but different limit be combined?

Tags: integration, multiple-integral

If there are two double integrals and they have the same size, is there a rule that supports combining them?

For example:
$$\int_{-1}^{1} \int_{-1}^{x} \left(1 + x\sin^2(y) + y^3\cos^4(x) \right)\, dy\, dx + \int_{-1}^{1} \int_{-1}^{y} \left(2 + x\sin^2(y) + y^3\cos^4(x) \right) \,dy \,dx $$ 
in the image's below, you can see they take of the same space but the limits are different. 
How is this solved?

limits graph:

[graph image of first integral limits](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w4mHs.png)

[graph image of second integral](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TyWZc.png)

Comment: switch the variables name in the second integral and you then you can merge them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can merge the domains of integration: if $f$ is continuous in $[-1,1]\times [-1,1]$ then 
$$\underbrace{\int_{x=-1}^{1} \int_{y=-1}^{x}}_{\text{triangle $(-1,-1)$, $(1,-1)$, $(1,1)$}}\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\! 
f(x,y)dx + \underbrace{\int_{y=-1}^{1} \int_{x=-1}^{y}}_{\text{triangle $(-1,-1)$, $(-1,1)$, $(1,1)$}} \!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!
f(x,y) dx dy$$
is equal to 
$$\underbrace{\int_{x=-1}^1\int_{y=-1}^1}_{\text{square $(-1,-1)$, $(1,-1)$, $(1,1)$, $(-1,1)$}}\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!
 f(x,y) dxdy.$$
Note that your $f(x,y)$ is a sum of products $g(x)\cdot h(y)$, therefore  to evaluate the double integral you may use linearity and 
$$\int_{x=-1}^1\int_{y=-1}^1 g(x)\cdot h(y) dxdy=\left(\int_{x=-1}^1 g(x) dx\right)\cdot \left(\int_{y=-1}^1 h(y) dy\right).$$
Finally recall that the integral of an odd function over $[-1,1]$ is zero.